# Stripe webhook test throws error in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, stripe-payments

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

at xxxxx.Controllers.ApiController.Index() in D:\Projects\xxxxxxx\Controllers\ApiController.cs:line 60

I am using stripe to send a test api request to the end point and result is 500 Any help appreciated.

If you any further info please don't hesitate.

```
  using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
  using System;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using System.IO;
  using Stripe;
  using xxxxx.Services.Interfaces;
  using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
  using System.Diagnostics;
  using xxxxxx.Models;

 namespace xxxxxxx.Controllers
{
[ApiController]
[Route("api/webhook")]    
public class ApiController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    private readonly IWebhookEventRepository _webhookEventRepository;

    public ApiController(IConfiguration config, 
        IWebhookEventRepository webhookEventRepository)
    {
        _config = config;
        _webhookEventRepository = webhookEventRepository;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public WebhookEvent WebhookEvent { get; set; }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var json = await new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

        Event stripeEvent;
        var KeyValue = _config.GetValue<string>("Stripe:WebhookSecret");            

        try
        {
            stripeEvent = EventUtility.ParseEvent(json);
            var signatureHeader = Request.Headers["Stripe-Signature"];
            stripeEvent = EventUtility.ConstructEvent(json,
            signatureHeader, KeyValue);

            Console.WriteLine($"Webhook notification with type: {stripeEvent.Type} found 
   for {stripeEvent.Id}");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Something failed {e}");
            return BadRequest();
        }

        try
        {
            switch (stripeEvent.Type)
            {
                case Events.CustomerSubscriptionCreated:
                    var subscription = stripeEvent.Data.Object as Subscription;

           *LINE 60*        WebhookEvent = new WebhookEvent()
                    {
                        EventType = subscription.Object,
                        Customer = subscription.Customer.ToString(),
                        CustomerId = subscription.CustomerId,
                        Created = subscription.Created,
                        Cancelled = subscription.CancelAt
                    };

                    await _webhookEventRepository.Add(WebhookEvent);                          
                    break;

                case Events.CustomerSubscriptionUpdated:
                    var update = stripeEvent.Data.Object as Subscription;
                    break;

                case Events.CustomerCreated:
                    var customer = stripeEvent.Data.Object as Stripe.Customer;
                    break;
                default:
                    Debug.WriteLine("Default case");
                    break;
            }

            return Ok();

        }
        catch (StripeException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message);
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This is line 60   WebhookEvent = new WebhookEvent()

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that's the line where you encounter an error? Which object is unexpectedly null?

Before I saw you line label I suspected that this might be a source of problems related to signature verification:

```
stripeEvent = EventUtility.ConstructEvent(json, signatureHeader, KeyValue);
```

`ConstructEvent` must be given the raw request body, and the previous line calling `ParseEvent` may mutate the reader such that you cannot use it here.

I'd suggest:

1. Try removing the superfluous call to `ParseEvent` -- you shouldn't
   need both
2. Debug exactly where the error is coming from and add
   more detail to your question if this doesn't allow you to figure it
   out.

Comment: Thank you I will check that out today I think you maybe correct. Sorry about the question quality I see it has been voted down. I will try to do better in the future.